# For a German website: how to translate "call me back"?

Tags: translation

I have added a ["call me back" form](http://teakmoebel.com/call-me-back) to our website but I'm thinking it might better to translate "call me back" into German. On the other hand I don't think "rufen Sie mich zurück" would be a nice way to translate this phrase.

1. Should I stick with "call me back",
2. change it to "rufen Sie mich zurück" or
3. use something completely different?

Comment: And another one: "Wir rufen **Ihnen** auch gerne zurück" must be "Wir rufen **Sie** auch gerne zurück"

Comment: Inwiefern willst Du Leute zurückrufen, nach dem sie Kontakt über die Webseite aufgebaut haben? Zurückrufen unterstellt, dass der vorige Kontakt auch ein Anrufen war. "Rufen Sie mich an" erscheint mir viel logischer und "Call me back" schon im Englischen falsch.

Comment: @KarmaFusebox: At least, the version with *Ihnen* would match the usage in some dialects ;)

Comment: @userunknown: "Zurückrufen unterstellt, dass der vorige Kontakt auch ein Anrufen war." - woraus leitest du denn das ab? Wieso sollte man beispielsweise als Antwort auf einen Brief nicht telefonisch zurückrufen oder als Antwort auf einen Anruf keine SMS zurückschreiben können? Das *zurück* drückt doch nur aus, dass sich die Richtung der Nachrichtenübermittlung nun umkehrt, und nicht, dass die Kommunikationsform zwangsläufig beibehalten wird.

Comment: Anbieter von Qualitätsmöbel**n**

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Nein. Wenn ich jmd. zurückschlage, dann heißt das nicht, dass er meine Mutter oder meine Religion beleidigt hat, sondern dass er mich vorher geschlagen hat. Wenn mir jemand eine SMS schickt, und ich rufe ihn darauf hin an, ist es kein Rückruf. Allerdings konnte man im Deutschen lange Zeit gut zwischen *zurückrufen* und *zurück rufen* unterscheiden, was die Rechtschreibreformer für zu viel der Subtilitäten gehalten haben, weswegen heute alle alles aus ein ander schreiben. Hitler hätte durchaus vermelden dürfen, es werde zurück geschossen, aber nicht zurückgeschossen. So mit Rufen.

Comment: @userunknown: "Wenn ich jmd. zurückschlage, dann heißt das nicht, dass er meine Mutter oder meine Religion beleidigt hat, sondern dass er mich vorher geschlagen hat. Wenn mir jemand eine SMS schickt, und ich rufe ihn darauf hin an, ist es kein Rückruf." - dann müssen wir es wohl dabei belassen, dass wir hierbei ein unterschiedliches Verständnis haben.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest "Wir rufen Sie zurück" for the title as well (not "Ihnen", by the way).

Comment: Definitely. This sounds like a promise; imperatives sound more as if they are directed towards the user (in German).

Comment: and add a comma: ", wenn Sie hier Ihre ..."

Comment: The "zurück" could also be replaced by "an": Since there was no call in the one direction, the "zurück" lacks some justification.

Comment: @guidot: There was a previous message transmission in one direction (by sending the completed form). That's what the *back* / *zurück* refers to.

Answer (score 1):

If I mean "you" as one single person, like "hey you, call me back" then "Ruf mich zurück" or "Rufen Sie mich zurück"(the formal verson) is correct.
If I want a group of people or a company in general to call me back it would be "Ruft mich zurück" or "Rufen sie mich zurück" as formal version, notice the "s" typed as small letter. But none of these variations looks or sounds good in german.

Maybe just "Rückrufwunsch"? 
"Wir rufen Sie zurück", answered by Ingmar is a good idea. Sounds good and trustfully. Or even "Wir rufen Sie gerne zurück" if you want to say hat you really pleased to call s.o. back.

I wouldn't stick with "call me back" as single English sentence on a German site.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, "(persons name), ruf mich an"

Comment: Oh no, that is not good. It reminds me of former advertisement of sex telephone hotlines, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNnFqLslvJM

Comment: Für eine Webseite? Duzen? Dass die Person eingeloggt und namentlich bekannt ist, habe ich nirgends gelesen. Wie würde man dann formulieren?